# How to create an Image object with a base-64 source?

Tags: javascript, php, image

I have a remote web page, on which I use CURL and DOMDocument to retrive the src attribute of an image.

I use the following code, mixing JS in a PHP echo

```
<?php 

$toEcho = "";
$toEcho .= // some stuff here...
$toEcho.="
<script>

    //I create the object
    var img = new Image();

    //I set the source with the PHP variable : I get an error because of unexpected token ":"
    img.src = $imgsrc;

</script>"
echo $toEcho;
?>
```

I checked the source, it is valid, and displays properly in my browser(s).

Where could this come from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the source like this:

```
img.src = '$imgsrc';
```

Comment: I already am in a big PHP variable that contains my JS...
I echo it at the end !

Comment: Then show your full code. Anyway, you need single quotes around the source.

Comment: Try `img.src = '$imgsrc';` (notice the qoutes)